# Unit Initialization order not as indicated in source

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe4

I have a project where multiple units have Initialization sections. I would like to control the order in which this blocks are executed.

According to the following [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2925472/add-code-before-initialization-of-units-in-delphi), this is based on the order in which the units were compiled, so ultimately the order should be based on the arrangement of units in the uses clause of the source DPR.

The following is the DPR source of my project:

```
program X;

uses
  Vcl.Forms,
  uMain in 'uMain.pas' {MainForm},
  uFooA in 'uFooA.pas',
  uFooB in 'uFooB.pas';

{$R *.res}

begin
  Application.Initialize;
  Application.MainFormOnTaskbar := True;
  Application.CreateForm(TMainForm, MainForm);
  Application.Run;

end.
```

My issue is that this simply isn't the order in which Initialization blocks are executed.

```
How it should be |  How it actually is
                 | 
  1. uMain       |     1.uFooA
  2. uFooA       |     2.uFooB  
  3. uFooB       |     3.uMain
```

I would love to provide a SSCCE but I simply am not able to re-produce this issue on a fresh project.

I've tried re-building the project with no success.

What am I missing?

Comment: Is uMain using uFooA and/or uFooB? In that case the used units are compiled first.

Comment: @UweRaabe, ah, yes they are, silly me ... Please post an answer so that I can accept.

Comment: I'm not sure an answer is needed here. Mason's explanation in the answer you link to says it all: *The compiler starts at the top of the DPR's uses clause and works its way down, and for each unit it finds, it does the same thing recursively: start at the start of the uses clause, try to compile each used unit that isn't already compiled, then compile the current unit. So if you can get your unit in before any of the other ones get compiled, then it will get initialized first.*

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, thanks for pointing that out, I've read it but I've skipped the most important part. :S

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Even though there is a rigorous way in which the compiler determines initialisation, it's very difficult for a human to accurately figure out and control when there are many units with many dependencies.

E.g. Your DPR may use `UnitA, UnitB, UnitC;` but if `UnitA` has dependencies on `UnitB` then UnitB has to be initialised first.

Admittedly, the feature of units having **initialization** and **finalization** sections can make adding functionality as simple as "add the unit". Although this seems great, in reality, on really large projects it tends to get in the way. Personally I consider the "feature" to be quite horrible.

The best and most reliable way to control the inialisation sequence of your units is to do so explicitly. E.g.

```
program X;

uses
  Vcl.Forms,
  uMain in 'uMain.pas' {MainForm},
  uFooA in 'uFooA.pas',
  uFooB in 'uFooB.pas';

{$R *.res}

begin
  Init_uMain;
  Init_uFooA;
  Init_uFooB;

  Application.Initialize;
  Application.MainFormOnTaskbar := True;
  Application.CreateForm(TMainForm, MainForm);
  Application.Run;

  Finalise_uFooB;
  Finalise_uFooA;
  Finalise_uMain;
end.
```

Obviously the above code lacks appropriate try..finallys and would get messy with many units needing initialisation. However, there are other techniques that can be applied to keep things manageable.